# Reading input from a particular file descriptor

Tags: c, file, unix, pipe, file-descriptor

If I know that input to my program will come from a file descriptor with a (non standard) ID, how do I read from it?

For example, if I need to read from a file descriptor with the ID of 3, how do I do it?

Also, is there an easy way to test this in BASH without having to create another program and piping?

This is what I've got so far:

```
char buffer[100];
FILE* fd = fdopen(3, "r");
fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, fd);
sscanf(buffer, "%d", &whatever);
```

It compiles but gets a segmentation error when I run it. I looked at it in gdb and it gets stuck at the fgets, so I guess I'm doing something wrong? Possibly cause there's no end of file coming in on file descriptor 3 when I'm testing (again, would be nice if I could properly test this in BASH).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bash, assuming your executable is "a.out", do

```
./a.out 3< testfile
```

to have testfile assigned to file descriptor 3

The same invocation works in bash, sh, zsh, ...
It does not work in csh, tcsh, ...

Comment: Thanks, this will make testing much easier. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't previously open it, there *is* no file with file descriptor 3. `fdopen()` fails and hence `fd` is `NULL`, resulting in a segmentation fault when trying `fgets()` on it.

Always check the return value of your function calls.

Comment: Thanks! How do I initially open it then? I would've thought that fdopen would do that.

Comment: When the program is run the way @pmg says, fdopen(3) succeeds. Anyway, +1 for checking the return values.

Comment: Actually, it works with the redirection posted in the other answer. Am I still doing something wrong even though it works or is my code ok as posted?

Comment: @che Ah ok, I will make sure to check the return values but am just happy that it actually works! :)